# Jmeter issue while recording and executing windows based authentication scripts

Tags: performance, jmeter

In one of my application during the initial login I need to give the windows authentication as the user name and password to login into the application. In Jmeter I was unable to proceed if i play back the captured step. Also I was unable to parametrise and create new values by executing the steps once again.

Application is developed in Sharepoint with windows based authentication.

Do any one have an idea about how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Login_Config_Element